# Master and Child Relationship in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

master and child relationship in netsuite /PLEASE  Help me ?I want to display the child records when master object is selecting in netsuite please give suggestion ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirements a bit to have us a better understanding.

Comment: I want to create two records in netsuite , one parent  record and one child record ,so that,when I select the parent record all the child records will be displayed with information ?so I am feeling some difficulties in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the child record setup, did you have the Allow Child Record Editing checked? and make sure that there is field on the child record that has a type of List/Record and List/Record is the parent record and the Record is Parent is checked.